# How to snapshot program data structures during the lifetime of a program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, persistence, snapshot, backups

I want to keep track of the changes that occur in certain data structures (dictionaries) during the lifetime of my python program. We can achieve this by either taking **snapshots** or **backups**. Backups are not 'memory friendly', as they require to store the whole structure in memory. So the neat way to do this is to take a snapshot instead (something like the way Git stages files).

1. Are there modules in python that offer this feature?
2. If not, are there any known algorithms for describing changes in data structures without copying the data?

I don't want to use databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save python data structures. If you then use the date(time) module for creating the filenames, you would get something like a snapshot:

```
import pickle
import datetime

def backup(your_data):
    with open(f"backup {datetime.datetime.now()}", "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(your_data, file)
```

For getting the data, use the [pickle.load method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Saving data with pickle means 'saving' the whole data, I am looking for a way to track changes without saving the newest version of the data each time a change happens.

Comment: json is more efficient and more readable than pickle.